# Restrict TYPO3 records to site root pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Is there an option to restrict record creation for special records to site roots (domain start pages) in TYPO3?

Comment: with "domain start pages" I guess you mean pages with "is_siteroot"=1 and for which there is a site configuration; with "restrict record creation for special records to site roots" you mean that you want to create specific CTypes only on that pages? I guess that one method is to use a specific fluid template for that pages and use EXT:content_defender

Comment: Not sure if it's what you are looking for, but maybe allowedNewTables and deniedNewTables can help you:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#deniednewtables

Comment: Hi @JulianHofmann, thx for the hint to the `deniedNewTables` I'll go for that and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know no such thing exits.

in TYPO3 its common to have "Global Records" on Page id 0 (root of the page tree)

and site/page specific records in sysfolders, UID configured in the extension /plugin which creates the recocrds